# Problem when sending file by sockets "is not supported between the instance of 'int' and '' bytes ''

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

Good afternoon everyone

I am trying to send a file using sockets in python3 however I get a small error when trying to send the file which is the following:

on the client's side:

```
Line 18
while current_size < size
TypeError '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'bytes'
```

While on the server side the connection ends

Try to convert the bytes of size `int (size)` to integers but it did not work

I hope you can help me

server.py

```
import socket
import os

servidor = socket.socket()
conexion = (socket.gethostname(),900)
servidor.bind(conexion)
servidor.listen(1)

cliente,direccion = servidor.accept()

longitud = os.path.getsize("imagen.jpg")

while True:
    datos = cliente.recv(1024).decode()
    mensaje = input("> ")
    cliente.sendall(mensaje.encode())
    if datos == "exit":
        cliente.sendall("exit".encode())
        break
    elif datos == "archivo":
        cliente.send(bytes(longitud))
        with open("imagen.jpg","rb") as file:
            d = file.read(1024)
            while d:
                cliente.send(d)
                d = file.read(1024)
servidor.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket

conexion = ("Pc-1",900)
cliente = socket.socket()
cliente.connect(conexion)

while True:
    msg = input("> ")
    cliente.sendall(msg.encode())
    respuesta = cliente.recv(1024)
    print(respuesta.decode())

    if msg == "archivo":
        size = cliente.recv(1024)
        size = bytes(size)
        current_size = 0
        bufer = b""
        while current_size < size:
            data = cliente.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            if len(data) + current_size<size:
                data = data[:size-current_size]
            bufer += data
            current_size += len(data)
        with open("recibido.jpg","wb") as file:
            file.write(bufer)
```

**UPDATE**

@MarkTolonen, You could be a bit more explicit with the little-endian and big-endian byte order .                                                                                                        Regarding the second part of your answer.
What I understood is that the server expects a length of, for example, 1 bytes, which could be the length of the file size length to be sent, for example:
File = 1024bytes
LongFile = 4 <- This number is sent and it is of extension number

Then the server now waits for an extension number 4 that would be 1024 for example.
That way, the information received by the server will be limited.
It is right?

Comment: current_size is int and size is in bytes

Comment: @Ruturaj,then current_size convert it to bytes; `bytes (current_size)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to send the size of the file as bytes over the socket.  To convert a Python integer to bytes, decide on how many bytes you want to send and choose little-endian or big-endian byte order:

```
>>> size = 100000
>>> size.to_bytes(4,'big')
b'\x00\x01\x86\xa0'
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\x00\x01\x86\xa0','big')
100000
```

One other problem you will have, is that a socket stream has no message boundaries.  Your `cliente.recv(1024)` could receive 0 (connection closed) or 1 to 1024 bytes.  The first four will be the size but the rest will be the beginning of the file.  You should buffer the receive until you have at least 4 bytes, then extract the first four bytes as the size.

Comment: i try send the length to siize file and next the length of the file for example

Comment: size = 100bytes . length =3 and the  server waiting 1byte in this case the number 3 and next waiting a length 3 on this case the number 100 is correct

Comment: @Angel no need to send size of file size. Just send 4-byte encoded file size, then the file data. Receiver decodes 4-byte size, then reads “size” bytes of data.